# Word to describe a person who expresses his or her feelings frequently?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for a word to describe a person (it can be a term of animal behavior) who expresses his or her feelings frequently, particularly through facial expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Consider **[demonstrative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/demonstrative?q=demonstrative)**

> (of a person) tending to show feelings, especially of affection, openly.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider the word **effusive**

1. expressing feelings of gratitude, pleasure, or approval in an unrestrained or heartfelt manner

Comment: effusive however is only for a select class of feelings (it doesn't address a person frequently expressing anger, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

**Expressive** is the word I would use here, such as, 'That person has an expressive face; it shows their emotions quite clearly.' Another suggestion may be **emotive** if they are always expressing how they feel.

Finally, the idiom "wears their heart on their sleeve" is used to describe someone who it's very easy to tell how someone feels.

Answer (score 2):

### Emotional

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emotional):

> (Of a person) having feelings that are easily excited and openly displayed: *he was a strongly emotional young man*